# cakephp vs sapphire/silverstripe framework for php

Tags: php, cakephp, silverstripe

Hi i'm  a newbie in php programming. Im curious to know which framework is better, cakephp or sapphire? And which framework is very close to the ruby on rails style? I have searched around the web, but a definite comparison between the two is not available.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No framework is *better* per se, [ask 10 developers and you get 11 opinions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cakephp+vs). It depends on your context and requirements which one is **better suited for you**. Voting to close as subjective and argumentative.

Comment: you are right abt though but im looking for a way to learn oop style and learn a framework which is very easily adaptable in a short span :)

Comment: It's still hard to tell *you* what's better for *you*. Just get started with one that seems sensible, maybe that has a good tutorial that clicks with you, and see how far you get.

Comment: thanks a lot :) i think cakephp probably has lotta support on the web compared to sapphire. :)

Comment: I think the quality/style of the documentation is quite important. Some frameworks concentrate almost entirely on API documentation with very little examples, which may or may not be exactly what you want. A lot has been written about Cake and their own documentation is pretty verbose, if that's what you're looking for Cake is probably a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to PHP, you probably should get familiar with PHP before going for a framework.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP is closer to ROR in terms of usage comparable to Sapphire, however..I'll also suggest learning PHP itself prior using framework.

Comment: not im a newbie when it comes to frameworks. sorry abt the wrong intro :P. but i have written a good amound of php codes in the past. but there is no sense of code re-usability or structure in my programming. Im looking for a way to adapt to a framework easily without much of a hassle. thanks :)